# Send int from second script to bool[list] from first script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer, boolean

How can I achieve Bool[int] for current weapon type identification?

WeaponController

```
public class WeaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool[] CurrentWeapon = new bool[2];

public bool Wrench;
public bool Pistol;

void Start()
{
    Wrench = CurrentWeapon[0];
    Pistol = CurrentWeapon[1];
}
}
```

WeaponSwitching

```
public class WeaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
public int selectedWeapon = 0;

void Update()
{
    Player.GetComponent<WeaponController>().CurrentWeapon.bool[Paste here] = selectedWeapon;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WeaponSwitching class, change `CurrentWeapon.bool[Paste here] = selectedWeapon;` to `CurrentWeapon[index] = value;`

You'll need to change `index` to the array index you want to change and `value` to a boolean value. Currently you are using the int selectedWeapon which will become `true` if it's equal to 1 and `false` if it's equal to 0.

It also looks like your code may have a few other issues

1. Both classes say `public class WeaponController`. They need to have different names.
2. A Wrench and Pistol boolean are being assigned on start, but won't do anything afterwards if they don't have more code.

An easier way to do this might be to use a `public int CurrentWeapon`in the WeaponController class instead of `bool` and change that from the WeaponSwitching class.

[Here is a similar question with someone having a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008973/unity-weapon-equipping-and-swapping-between-them-arena-shooter-style/73010150#73010150)

Comment: 1. It's just a typo on the forum
2. Thanks, for a long time I could not decide in which script to use it, I rewrote it the other way around.

You're right, link with similar question. I adapted part of the code for myself, but since our questions have a different task, the results turned out to be different.

I was able to pass the int value to bool list, now my bools turn on but when switching they do not turn off.

Comment: The problem is in this piece of code: `if (i == selectedWeapon)`, i do `CurrentWeapon[selectedWeapon] = true;` and it switches, but when i try to turn off the previous bool in `else` `CurrentWeapon[selectedWeapon] = false;` it doesn't include anything

Comment: @Alexey It sounds like this question has been answered. Mark the answer here and post a new question with updated code - I'll take a look at what you've got now. Good job on getting that first part working!

Comment: I didn't change anything and on the fifth try everything worked.

Comment: @Alexey Awesome! Unity probably recompiled and loaded your script. I thought what you said in the previous comment sounded pretty reasonable